# POST request in urllib python3

Tags: python, post, flask, urllib

I'm having a problem sending a POST request to my flask server using the urllib library. Everything in my server has been testing using Postman And Advanced REST Client so I'm kiiiinda confident my server doesn't have any seemingly obvious errors, however I am getting a 500 error when using this code.
I've tried a lot of stack overflow posts and the answers listed on there but have yet to find a solution that works. 
In general what the server has are routes for /name/add which takes a POST request to receive a name to add to a global list while /names returns a dictionary with the value as a list of string names. Just really stumped because it all works perfectly fine on postman and ARC :(

```py
   pkt = parse.urlencode({'name':'Hayden'}).encode('ascii')
   req = request.Request('http://127.0.0.1:5000/name/add', pkt)
   with request.urlopen(req) as response:
        print(response.read())
```

The server code is as such:

```py
APP = Flask(__name__)

NAMES = []

@APP.route("/name/add", methods=['POST'])
def add_name():
    '''
    Adds a new name to the NAMES list
    '''
    data = request.get_json()
    NAMES.append(data['name'])
    return {}

@APP.route("/names", methods=['GET'])
def ret_names():
    '''
    Displays the NAMES list
    '''
    return dumps({
        'name':str(NAMES)
    })

@APP.route("/name/remove", methods=['DELETE'])
def rm_name():
    '''
    Removes a name from the NAMES list
    '''
    data = request.get_json()
    NAMES.remove(data['name'])
    return {}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP.run(port=5000)
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/import/reed/3/z5265106/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/import/reed/3/z5265106/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/import/reed/3/z5265106/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/import/reed/3/z5265106/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/import/reed/3/z5265106/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/import/reed/3/z5265106/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "simple.py", line 18, in add_name
    NAMES.append(data['name'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Usually the server is helpful and returns an error text with the 500 error that describes what went wrong. Try printing the whole response and it might help debugging this

Comment: @pastaleg hey sorry should've posted it earlier, put it in now

Comment: Hmm, so the server tells us that `data` is not a dictionary. Could you try removing the `.encode('ascii')` that you have in the client?

Comment: Thing is the requests.Request function needs the data to be bytes :( It doesn't contact the server if I remove it, instead I get an error from the test file saying TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. 
It cannot be of type str.

Comment: Aha, then use the more standard `.encode("utf-8")` to preserve the structure of the dictionary

Comment: Got the original error from the server again :') It's so painful I've been stuck on this for days now

Comment: Okay, I tried running your client code and it works fine. Maybe the flask server does something weird

Comment: yeah you're probably right, I've added my server code. First time using flask so really don't know much about it yet

Comment: Okay! Great, I think the issue is get_json(). See my answer for a solution for that

Answer (score 2):

Try this code and see if it works:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/name/add'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
values = {'name' : 'Hayden' }
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Also, check out this [Link](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html)

Please consider putting your code in a Try/Catch so you can see what's the problem

```
try: urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print(e.reason)
```

And In order to use your GET metho try this:

```
 import urllib.request
 contents = urllib.request.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:5000/names").read()
```

Comment: Hi Erfan, this hasn't worked for me :( Do you think there's something potentially wrong with my server side?

Comment: Hello Aniket, please make sure your server returns a valid JSON response so it won't be NON-TYPE and Python can recognize it.

Comment: I believe it does, but I might be mistaken. I've added my server code to the post if that'll help debugging

Answer (score 0):

In your server code, you are reading the request with `.get_json()` which in case the data type does not match json returns `Nothing`. A nothing type matches the error you get where there is no '`name`' access. More documentation about get_json() here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json

So to solve your problem, you can replace the previous urlencode function with json.dumps() to serialize the data for the request. Remember to keep the .encode() to make sure you send the request as bytes and not string.

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json

pkt = json.dumps({'name':'Hayden'}).encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request('http://127.0.0.1:5000/name/add', pkt, method='POST')
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
  print(response.read())
```

Comment: I really thought this would be it, but still getting the same error from the server after using json.dumps :(

Comment: Hmm, and you included the method='POST' in the Request() as well?

Comment: Yeah I added the method='POST'

Comment: @AniketChavan One more thing to try is to use .get_json(force=True) in your server code to force the json convertion to happen